# How can I load my object in Angular/rxjs that requires 2 API calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using Angular 6.

I have the following classes:

```
export class MyItem{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  gizmo: Gizmo;
};

export class Gizmo{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  color: string;
};
```

I have to make 2 API calls.
1 - To get the array of MyItems.
2 - To get the gizmo of a given MyItem.

I've tried this:

```
this.myItemService.get<MyItem[]>(
    new FindParameters({ name: name })
  ).pipe(tap(z => {
    z.forEach(function (item) {
      this.gizmoService.get(item.id)
        .subscribe(z => {
          item.gizmo = z;
        });
    });

  }))
  .subscribe(x => this.totalCount = x.length);
```

However the gizmoService appears to not be in scope inside the function. (If I pull it out the service is fine)

So how can I load my object that will require 2 separate API calls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple RxJS AJAX Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793042/multiple-rxjs-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `.subscribe()` into a `.subscribe()` is an anti-pattern and must be avoided at all cost. What you should do instead is merge your api calls into one single observable and get the end result with a `.subscribe()`.

From what I see, here's how you should transform your observable to get your gizmo data into your item data:

```
this.myItemService.get<MyItem[]>(
    new FindParameters({ name: name })
).pipe(
    mergeMap((myItems: MyItem[]) => {
        const gizmoRequestArray: Observable<MyItem>[] = myItems.map(item => {
            return this.gizmoService.get(item.id).pipe(
                map(z => {
                    item.gizmo = z;
                    return item;
                })
            );
        });
        return combineLatest(gizmoRequestArray);
    })
)
.subscribe(x => this.totalCount = x.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty straight forward, just be aware that this doesn't preserve the same order of items.

```
this.myItemService.get<MyItem[]>(...)
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(), // flatten the array into single emission
    mergeMap(item => this.gizmoService.get(item.id).pipe(
      map(gizmo => {
        item.gizmo = gizmo;
        return item;
      })
    )),
    toArray(), // turn all result into an array again
  )
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: You can also pass `resultSelector` as the second parameter of `mergeMap`. This way you can omit writing nested `.pipe` and `map`

Comment: result selectors are deprecated

Comment: I think you missed an operator in the nested pipe

Comment: @OlesSavluk Not in this case. Result selector would be useful if I was using `map` after `mergeMap` not inside it.

Comment: Oh, `resultSelector` is really deprecated and will be removed in v7. Thanks for pointing this out!