# How to populate Observable<Object[]> from 2 API calls

Tags: angular, reactjs

I need to return an `Observable<MyResult[]>`.

To accomplish this I need to make 2 separate API calls to load the data.

1. To load the MyItem
2. To load the Gizmos[] for each item.

I asked a similar question but the difference there was that I was loading the second API into the object of the first API.  This time I need to load both API calls into a separate object.

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705919/how-can-i-load-my-object-in-angular-rxjs-that-requires-2-api-calls)

```
export class MyItem{
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

export class Gizmo{
  id: string;
  itemId: string;
  name: string;
  color: string;
};

export class MyResult{
  item: MyItem;
  gizmos: Array<Gizmo>;
}
```

I have read up on React but it's still not clicking for me what I can/can't do syntactically.

EDIT:

I am looking for the following results:

```
{   
    "MyResult": [ 
        { "MyItem": { "id": "100", "name": "Bob", "Gizmo": [{"id": "1", "itemId": "100", "name": "Gizmo1", "color": "Red"}, { "id": "2", "itemId": "100", "name": "Gizmo2", "color": "Blue" } ] }}, 
        { "MyItem": { "id": "200", "name": "Sally", "Gizmo": [{ "id": "3", "itemId": "200", "name": "Gizmo3", "color": "Black" }, { "id": "4", "itemId": "200", "name": "Gizmo55", "color": "White" }] }}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use the combineLatest observable `combineLatest(firstcall, secondcall).pipe(map((firstResult, secondeResult) => ..)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've captured what you want in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqeuvd)

Check the browser console to see the result.

Here's the main controller code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, combineLatest } from 'rxjs'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { MyItem, Gizmo, MyResult } from './classes'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doApiCalls().subscribe((result: MyResult) => {
      console.log('result', result)
    })
  }

  doApiCalls(): Observable<MyResult> {
    // mimic an Observable response from an API
    const firstCall: Observable<MyItem> = of(new MyItem('100', 'fred'));

    // mimic an Observable response from an API
    const secondCall: Observable<Gizmo[]> = of([
      new Gizmo('1', '100', 'gizmo1', 'red'),
      new Gizmo('2', '100', 'gizmo2', 'blue')
    ]);

    const result: Observable<MyResult> = combineLatest(firstCall, secondCall).pipe(
      map(([item, gizmos]) => new MyResult(item, gizmos))
    )

    return result
  }
}
```

Comment: How would this change if MyItem returns an array. (100, Fred),(200, Sally) And Gizmos are ('1', '100', 'gizmo1', 'red'), ('2', '100', 'gizmo2', 'blue'), ('3', '200', 'gizmo1', 'red'), ('4', '200', 'gizmo3', 'purple')